# Should a server accept &amp; instead of & in an URL get request?

Tags: php, http, server, server-configuration

**INTRO**
I will give you an example so my question may be better understandable. I don't need "help" in programming matters, just information about this topic!

**EXAMPLE**
I tried out an [API for getting weather information](http://api.worldweatheronline.com/) for a specific position and stumbled upon a problem. I built my url to request data like this:

```
$params['q']            = $latitude .','. $longitude; // 48.14,11.58
$params['format']       = $format; //json
$params['num_of_days']  = $numOfDays; //1
$params['key']          = self::APIKEY;

$url = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx'
$url .= '?'. http_build_query($params);
```

The final URL looked like this

http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=48.13743%2C11.57549&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=APIKEY

However, when requesting the data for this URL with cURL I received the error that no api-key was provied. As I found out, the problem were use of `&amp;` symbols in the URL. When I used the `http_build_query` method like this:

`$url .= '?'. http_build_query($params, null, '&');`

The URL looked like this: http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=48.13743%2C11.57549&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=APIKEY

**QUESTION**
Now what I want to ask, if this is an expected behavior from a server. I know from several other APIs (Facebook, Foursquare, etc.) that they accept `&amp;` instead of `&` in the URL and work like expected.

Is there a standard? Should a server be able to accept `&amp;` or is it "wrong" to accept it and should only `&` be accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Somehow I can't edit my post. The first URL should look like this: `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=48.13743%2C11.57549&amp;format=json&amp;num_of_days=1&amp;key=APIKEY`. The argument seperators should be `&amp;` not `&`. Hope that clears something up!

Comment: This question cannot be answered clearly as you are asking for opinions. And no, in my opinion a server must not understand any URL format that results from parsing errors earlier in the call chain.

Comment: I thought there might be a standard like this one: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html that tells us if the `&amp;` should be accepted by a server or not. But if I understand you correctly you say, in your opinion, that a server should not be able to accept `&amp;` since the correct argument seperator is `&`? - Upvoted for sharing your opinion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML entities like `&amp;` are not a part of URI specification. As far as [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) is concerned, `&` is a sub-delimiting character, therefore if a server receives a query string like this:

```
foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

and parses it to the following key-value pairs:

```
'foo' => '1',
'amp;bar' => '2'
```

it is behaving correctly.

To make things even more interesting, `;` is a reserved sub-delimiter, too, but:

> if a reserved character is found in a URI component and no delimiting
> role is known for that character, then it must be interpreted as
> representing the data octet corresponding to that character's encoding
> in US-ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the first time I stumbled upon t his problem and I'm using `http_build_query` quite often, so how come that Facebook and other APIs don't have the problem with the `&amp;` instead of `&`? Nice answer, upvoted!

Comment: @Musterknabe They might've made their servers de-entitize `&amp;`s but that's not something that's required or expected from every server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a reason http_build_query uses `&amp;` then instead of `&`? Should I really always pass the two additional parameters to be sure, that there aren't encoding/decoding problems with the URL?

Comment: @Musterknabe Actually, `&` *is* the default separator for `http_build_query` as stated by the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and confirmed by a quick test (http://3v4l.org/O28nR). The fact that your PHP version/build uses `&amp;` instead seems to be a bug, as mentioned by some people in the comments section of the doc page. I guess you'll be safest always providing the `&` manually.

Comment: The people stating this bug all have php 5.3, I'm however using sth above 5.5 (can check tomorrow). Should I report it as a bug, if my php version creates `&amp;` as a default argument seperator?

Comment: I have no idea what fixed it, but the next day the problem wasn't there anymore. the php.ini had set argument.seperator.output defined with `&`